# sendMessage to SQS from Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am building an SPA with Django REST as the backend. Right now I am using the standard Django authentication system and `User` models.

I would like the JS running on the SPA to be able to insert messages into an AWS SQS (i.e. `sendMessage`).

AWS has [these doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Sending_a_message) on calling `sendMessage` from JS in the browser.

They also provide [these docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html) on how to authenticate the user. My thought right now is to use Amazon Cognito. From the [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/):

> Q: What if I register and authenticate my own users?
>
> Amazon Cognito can integrate with your existing identity system. With
>   a simple API call you can retrieve a Cognito ID for your end users
>   based on your own unique identifier for your users. Once you have
>   retrieved the Cognito ID and OpenID Token Cognito provides, you can
>   use the Cognito client SDK to access AWS resources and synchronize
>   user data.

Am I correct that for this to work, I would need to:

1. Create an IAM user for each user in my system. Or do I just need one IAM role?
2. When the user logins in my site (Django backend), I would have my backend then make ["a simple API call [to] retrieve a Cognito ID"](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities)
3. Send that Cognito ID when the user loads the SPA.
4. User the Cognito ID from the JS running in the browser to call `sendMessage` to the SQS queue

Am I missing something here? Is there someway to remove the Django User backend and just user IAM Users so that I can avoid having to keep the two users lists in sync? I found [this project](https://github.com/viewworld/django-auth-iam/) but it does not seem to be maintained.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that there might be an alternative method of doing this where I don't use Cognito at all but rather expose an endpoint that can [sign requests, "Query Request Authentication"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/Query_QueryAuth.html). [This Heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python#direct-uploading) talks a little about building a signing service.

Is this in fact an alternative option and if so what are the pro/cons of these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Cognito does not require you to register IAM users, just the 2 IAM roles. A slight modification to what you would need to do:

1. Create an Amazon Cognito Identity pool, configure with your developer provider.
2. Update the IAM roles associated with your pool to allow access to the services you want (for instance SQS).
3. From your Django backend, call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity to get the OpenId Connect token and identity Id for this user, return this to your JS application.
4. Configure your [CognitoCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html#Configuring_AWS_CognitoIdentityCredentials) in the JS SDK. In the logins map, use the key **cognito-identity.amazonaws.com** and the value as the token returned from your Django backend.
5. Use the JS SDK to call SQS or any other services you wish from your application.

While using pre-signed URLs for SQS can work, using Cognito with the JS SDK will allow you to leverage other services supported by the SDK (DynamoDB, SNS, S3, etc).

Comment: If I wanted to rate-limit the number of inserts that a given user can `sendMessage`, does either the `pre-signed URL` or `Cognito` approach have some mechanism for allowing this? One thought would be to check rate on pre-signing and also set a very short expiration, but this doesn't explicitly control number of sends.

Comment: @AlexRothberg Unfortunately neither solution allows this level of control.

Comment: Is it possible to limit the values that can be set for `DelaySeconds`? i.e. I always want to use the queue default?

Comment: @AlexRothberg Unfortunately not, the SDK is only able to do as much limitation as is available in the API.